# Change theme with old gnome look

Tags: 12.04, gnome, themes

I really like the old gnome theme ([photo](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/extra/LINUX/large/ubuntuhardypreview-large_011.jpg)), and I was wondering if there's a posibility to install it on ubuntu 12.04?

If so, tell me how please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can download human icon theme but it will probably have a lot of missing icons.

```
sudo apt-get install human-icon-theme
```

[image]

You can also try gnome-colors wich has six diferent color schemes and resembles the original gnome2 icon set(you can also make your own color schemes with the source code).

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/GNOME-colors?content=82562

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-colors
```

[image]

Comment: And still can't find the theme in `gnome-tweak-tool` .. I don't want the current gnome theme, I want the old one.

Comment: If you are using the Unity desktop you need to install Ubuntu Tweak tool to change icons on it.

Comment: I just realized the 'old one' is neither gnome iconset but the old humanity theme.

Comment: Not actually... I installed the old one and doesn't look like the one in the picture

Answer (score 0):

If you want panels with many configurable applets and programs menu from old Ubuntus I can recommend you install XFCE environment, or Xubuntu OS.
I am using second option and it look like this:[image]